# Frontend Routes not showing in Laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel

I am having issues with routing in my projects. In my project I have a laravel backend and an angular frontend. My laravel backend has a route wildcard in my web.php that allows my angular app to control routing. Here is my web.php file

```
<?php


    Route::domain('localhost')->group(function(){
        Route::view('/{path?}/', 'index');
    });
```

Now if I visit a route such as localhost:8000/login it works fine but when i visit a page such as localhost:8000/admin/login I get a 404 laravel not found error. What do i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to actually catch all, you need to use a regex pattern. Laravel's routing takes into account the segments `/` in the URL. You need to tell it to accept anything:

```
Route::view('{all}', 'index')->where('all', '.*');
```

Comment: Worked like charm. It kinda makes sense. Thanks